# sbt unresolved dependency publishing to nexus

Tags: sbt, nexus, sonatype

I publish my project to nexus/sonatype staging repo. Then I try to pull that dependency with sbt update on another project.

I get an unresolved dependency error. sbt shows me all the directories it tried, including the path for the staging repo I expected to succeed.

I initially thought it was a deployment/delay thing with nexus (waiting for the package to propagate) but I can reliably hit the same pom file link that sbt says failed from a browsers with no problems (cut 'n paste the precise URL).

Does sbt have some kind of resolution cache not cleared by a clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pom can be downloaded from Nexus then the issue isn't with Nexus, it is with SBT. You might try explicitly running update from SBT to clear it's cache.